# php - make date 'D' a full word

Tags: php, date, strtotime

For example I input a date and get that value

```
2016-07-07
```

Then Passing the value

```
$c = $_POST['c']
```

But Im trying to just wanna get the **full** word of the day only. For instance that produces `Thu` instead of `Thursday` is there any way for it? this is my code `$cc = date('D', strtotime($c));`

Answer (score 0):

Never felt so embarrassed before. I use this [site](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

and I just change the

```
$cc = date('D', strtotime($c));
```

To

```
$cc = date('l', strtotime($c));
```

Comment: Hehehe i got confused by what is said. `A full textual representation of the day of the week` I'm expecting something like `A full textual representation of the day` and I'm wide awake like 50 hours so I'm so sorry for the misconduct